# Python get module reference from another package, knowing package and module name

Tags: python

How can I get the reference to a module from another package, by name?

Considering:

```
genericCall(packageName, moduleName, methodName):
    #Call moduleName.methodName
    #knowing that the moduleName is in packageName
```

Where

```
packageName="p1"
moduleName="m1"
methodName="f1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to import either module or package, and to do it by name, you can use [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) or [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

```
import importlib

def genecirCall(package_name, module_name, function_name):
    # import module you need
    module = importlib.import_module('%s.%s' % (package_name, module_name))
    getattr(module, function_name)() # make a call
```

Note, that in this example, the `module` variable will be local.

Answer (score 2):

`__import__` provides the ability to import packages dynamically. Then after importing the package, you could use `getattr` to get the module object from the module name (This is called `introspection` in Python). Since both functions are built-in functions, you could use them without explicitly importing other packages. The [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) provides more information of these built-in functions.

```
package = __import__(packageName)
module = getattr(package, moduleName)
method = getattr(module, methodName)
method(...)
```

Comment: Yes, but I only know string representations of package and moduleName...so getattr can't be used like you've suggested

Comment: @Ameoo It seems I misunderstood your question. Answer updated.

Comment: Answer should not consist **only** code. It would be much more valuable to add explanation for used methods and their potential shortcomings

Comment: Be careful with `module = getattr(package, moduleName)`. Importing a package doesn't import its files as modules into the package namespace (i.e., files and modules aren't the same thing).